# Concatenate Variables in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code and it works. but ugly :

```
var origin = "";
$.each(json, function(i,o){
    origin += "<option value="+o.city_id+">"+o.city_name+"</option><option value="+o.province_id+">"+o.province+"</option><option value="Indonesia">"Indonesia"</option>";
});

$("#product_seg_area").append(origin);
```

then I decided to clean up the code so it look much cleaner :

```
var origin = "";
$.each(json, function(i,o){
    var seg_city += "<option value="+o.city_id+">"+o.city_name+"</option>";
    var seg_province += "<option value="+o.province_id+">"+o.province+"</option>";
    var seg_country += "<option value="Indonesia">"Indonesia"</option>";
    origin = seg_city + seg_province + seg_country;
});

$("#product_seg_area").append(origin);
```

but it seems concatenating 3 variables in to one variable makes my code stop working. what did I missed here?

Comment: You should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(json, function(i,o){
    var seg_city += "<option value="+o.city_id+">"+o.city_name+"</option>";
    var seg_province += "<option value="+o.province_id+">"+o.province+"</option>";
    var seg_country += "<option value="Indonesia">"Indonesia"</option>";
    origin = seg_city + seg_province + seg_country;
});
```

Issue is `seg_city` is not defined. At first round you try to concatenate `html` with undefined. So your code stooped working.

To get it working,

```
var seg_city, seg_country, seg_province;
$.each(json, function(i,o){
        seg_city = "<option value="+o.city_id+">"+o.city_name+"</option>";
        seg_province = "<option value="+o.province_id+">"+o.province+"</option>";
        seg_country = "<option value="Indonesia">"Indonesia"</option>";
        origin = seg_city + seg_province + seg_country;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
var origin = "";
$.each(json, function(i,o){
    var seg_city = "<option value='"+o.city_id+"'>"+o.city_name+"</option>";
    var seg_province = "<option value='"+o.province_id+"'>"+o.province+"</option>";
    var seg_country = "<option value='Indonesia'>"Indonesia"</option>";
    origin += seg_city + seg_province + seg_country;
});

$("#product_seg_area").append(origin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line from :

```
origin = seg_city + seg_province + seg_country;
```

to

```
origin += seg_city + seg_province + seg_country;
```